# I have a program of spilting words but i don't want it in array

Tags: php, arrays

Hey i have a php program which is to spilt the words. I wanted it not to come in array. Instead of array i wanted it in div or span. Please help me to solve these problem. Thanks in advance.
Here is my php code

```
<?php

    function str_split_len($str, $len)
    {
        if( $len > strlen($str) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        $strlen = strlen($str);
        $result = array();
        $words = ($strlen / $len);

        for( $x = 1; $x <= $len; $x++ )
        {
            $result[] = substr($str, 0, $words);
            $str = substr($str, $words, $strlen); 
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /* Example */
    $res = str_split_len("Split me !haha!", 3);
    print_r($res);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use implode function to join array:

```
$res = str_split_len("Split me !haha!", 3);
echo '<span>'.implode('</span><span>', $res).'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a string instead of an array and concatenate the parts with `<div>` or `<span>`:

```
<?php
function str_split_len($str, $len)
{
    if( $len > strlen($str) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $strlen = strlen($str);
    $result = '';
    $words = ($strlen / $len);

    for( $x = 1; $x <= $len; $x++ )
    {
        $result .= '<div>'.substr($str, 0, $words).'</div>';
        $str = substr($str, $words, $strlen); 
    }

    return $result;
}

/* Example */
$res = str_split_len("Split me !haha!", 3);
echo $res;
?>
```

And you will get

```
<div>Split</div><div> me !</div><div>haha!</div>
```